# Warning: Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't see what is wrong with my code but I got warning of

**Any use of a keyed object should be wrapped**

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    const data = {
      "fruits":[
        {"name":"banana","value":true},
        {"name":"watermelon","value":false},
        {"name":"lemon","value":true},
      ]
    }
    return (      
        {data.fruits.map(obj => 
         <div>
           <label>{obj.name}</label>
           <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} type="checkbox" defaultChecked={obj.true}/>
         </div>
         )}
    );
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/nuzeqinave/1/edit?html,js,console,output

What is wrong here?I did wrap everything in a `<div>`

Comment: Shouldn't `obj.true` be `obj.value`?

Comment: The jsbin code is different than the code you posted. The code you posted does not produce the output you posted (but the jsbin does). Please update your question to include the **complete example**.

Answer (score 0):

i think the whole return of your render method must be wrapped:

```
render() {
const data = {
  "fruits":[
    {"name":"banana","value":true},
    {"name":"watermelon","value":false},
    {"name":"lemon","value":true},
  ]
}
return (
  <div>
    {data.fruits.map(obj => 
     <div>
       <label>{obj.name}</label>
       <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} type="checkbox" defaultChecked={obj.true}/>
     </div>
     )}
  </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't include the problem code, but your [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/nuzeqinave/1/edit?html,js,console,output) does. The error is because you are trying to render an object literal here:

```
<p>{this.state.fruits}</p>
```

If you are just trying to output the object for debugging purposes you can encode it as a JSON string:

```
<p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.fruits)}</p>
```

Which, in your example you just set `state.fruits` to an empty object and you never update it, so you simply get the rendered output:

```
{}
```